# JQuery bound click function becoming unbound with ASP.Net AJAX postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Greetings all,

I have a simple JQuery function which is bound to an ASP:Button and fires when the submit button is clicked, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server"
                Text="Send" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

This code runs correctly the first time the page is loaded, but never runs again after clicking Submit (and a post/postback occurs). The asp button code is within an UpdatePanel. It seems like the JQuery code is being "unregistered" or unbound after the postback. I have a ScriptManager control on the page but this is all I'm doing with it:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ContactFormScriptManager" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/contact-form.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I suspect there's more I need to do with ScriptManager to make sure my JQuery code stays registered, but I'm not sure what. Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-NorthK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz) is right about the solution but I thought you may want some explanation as to why this works:

```
$(function () {
  $(".btnSubmit").live("click", function() {
    alert("button clicked");
  });
});
```

It's not that it's being "unregistered", it's that the elements in the UpdatePanel are completely destroyed/replaced by new elements.  Since the click handler is stored on those elements (well, not exactly, but close) it's not automatically created for the new elements.

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) however works differently, it adds an event handler to `document` which isn't getting replaced.  It listens for the `click` event to [bubble up the DOM](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and reach document.  When it gets there it checks if the element the event came from matches the selector...if the selector matches, it executes the handler.

Comment: @Sarfraz and @nick,

Thanks very much.  That works like a charm and the explanation helps a alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSubmit").live('click', function () {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```